# Access a variable from Sub Sub Popup Child window

Tags: javascript, windows, popup, global-variables, scope

I have many popup windows (same page will open in many popup windows), i wanted to track all popup windows objects by pushing into an array, if have saved tacked array variable in parent window (Main window), then how can i access that array from sub child popup window.

## Example :

**Window Names:**  Main_win, Subchild1, Subchild2, Subchild3, Subchild4.

```
var ex_arr = []; // is in Main_win,
```

Now i need to access **ex_arr** from **Subchild2** window

**Note**: here the opener of **Subchild2** window is **Subchild1**.
Please give me solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.opener` should return a reference to the window from where the current window was opened.

`window.opener.ex_arr[ .....`

Comment: Yaa, what you said is absolutely correct, but here my requirement is it should be able to access the variable in topmost window, in my example above, Main_win(main window), Subchild1(popup 1), Subchild2(popup 2). Now i need to access variable in side Main_win from Subchild2, so here Subchild2 opener is Subchild1,

Comment: @user2746392: Follow the white rabit. `w=window; a=null; while((!a) && w && w.opener){if(w.opener.ex_arr) {a=w.opener.ex_arr;}else{w = w.opener;}}` (not tested, just to show the idea)

Comment: Thanks MC ND, This sounds good, i will check and let you know.

Comment: Hi MC ND, do you have any idea on how to declare global variable in JMVC(Javascript MVC), and this way we will get the value, but how we can set the same value.

Answer (score 0):

do `window.ex_arr` if `ex_arr` was declared as global.

Comment: I am using JMVC framework, even i declared as global, it taking the `ex_arr` from the popup window itself.